# Unity Textures Display as Lines on Vertical Surfaces

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I placed a texture onto the structure in the picture and the texture renders fine on all horizontal surfaces but renders as a bunch of lines. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Both scripting and Unity-based solutions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the tiling values of the materials of your walls

Comment: @Chico3001 It's not the tiling values. When I mess with then I can change it on the horizontal planes, but I can only change the line density of the vertical planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either a problem with the uv map of the model or the material has some special mappings.

You can create a simple checker material and attach it to the wall: If it looks checkered the problem is the material, if it is not checkered the problem is the uv map of the model.

Comment: @aalmighty So I figured out why it does that. The model is made by taking a plane and elevating parts to create the structure. Is there a better way about building the structure, like flatten a cube and elevate it surfaces? I think that may still be problematic because a 3D object is just 4 planes right?

Comment: The way the model is created does not matter, but you need to create a uv map for the object after making changes. if you want to avoid that you could use a triplanar shader in unity. triplanar shaders use the world coordinates instead of the uv map.

Comment: I managed to fix it by rebuilding the structure with ProBuilder in Unity and flipping the faces. Although it is much faster to do it the first way so I’ll have to try out your idea. Do you have any good links on how to do the UV mapping and triplanar shader?

Comment: UV mapping: I do not know what 3D-Software you are using, but google should help you there. Writing triplanar shaders is not so difficult, there is a node in shadergraph (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Triplanar-Node.html) or you can check catlike codings tutorial (https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/advanced-rendering/triplanar-mapping)